# Is a text is composed of the following elements?: header, body, footer, insert

Tags: terminology

I'm creating software where users can build a textfile by inserting small snippets of text into one file. the user interface currently contains the following four buttons:

Add a header
Add a footer
Add a body
add an insert

I'm worried about the use of the word "body". What do you think of the alternative "Add a main part"? In general, **how do you call the portion of a text that is NOT a header,footer or attachment**? I'm finding that the word body translates very poorly to dutch, as we only use the word body in the literal sense of "the body of an organism", not the abstract meaning of "content of a text"

My second issue is with "insert". In our software we already use the word attachment, as in an e-mail attachment, so we needed to use a word that kind of means the same but sounds really distinct from the word "attachment". Are there better alternatives? Perhaps an addendum or appendix?

Comment: Stick with _body_; stay away from _main part_. See Meaning #24 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/body).

Comment: Hi, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing yours to *“What do you call the portion of a text....?”* Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In web development lingo, this area of the text is often called the **Content**, or **Content Area**.

This arises from the notion that all other areas are contextual to the "body" / content.  Thus, you give that area a term that focuses on its primacy.

Since you are translating, consider the above even more closely.  Terms like *corpus*, *base*, or perhaps *discussion* will be similes, in different situations.

---

Regarding your second question, **Appendix** is a very suitable term.

*Insert*, being potentially-confused as a verb, is not well-suited.  Verbs are action-oriented items, not objects / nouns.